# Magmi not displaying back to configuration

Tags: magento-1.7, magmi

Currently I am facing very weird problem in Magmi in which i am importing the  820  product .It successfully import all the product but does not display back to configuration link while after cancel it display link.

it is continuously posting :

```
POST http://xxx.com/magmi/web/magmi_progress.php 200 OK 324ms prototype.js (line 1731)
```

I have also tried with new magmi but same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to reindexing or post import phase not finished yet.

reindexing may take some time depending on how many items are in the DB.

Comment: i am having total 1640 test product and it might be more ...after complete import.

Comment: Is it problem of the disabling the cache on live??.

Comment: i am waiting for 1+ hr for back to configuration link.is it taking that much time to re-index??. i think it might have different problem. By the way i am having Ubuntu server is it make any difference

Comment: 1640 products is a small amount, it shouldn't take that much to reindex. so maybe some ajax calls in the UI return with an error, preventing the end of import to work correctly. could you try running the profile using CLI  instead of Web UI ?

Comment: My Last product which is configurable is not updating. How can i do with CLI?

Comment: have you checked the configurable plugin in your profile ?

Comment: Yes i have , sometime it import and sometime not , i think that i getting 500 error after sometime which might create problem , i will test it in local then i would try in server

Comment: I am getting  http://XXX/magmi/web/magmi_run.php not found does it create problem. If yes so then i have to focus on 500 error fix

Comment: i think the best method is : run your import using magmi cli interface script (located at magmi/cli/magmi.cli.php), see wiki for usage. then a 500 on magmi_run script is a big problem since that's the script executing the import using Web UI (Which is not the preferred method , UI is here to setup & test profiles, CLI is the preferred method for executing imports)